# Raw printer driver retrieve data

Tags: c#, printing

I am using the code on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091 to send raw data to a USB printer.
This doc only explains how to send data, but some printers do also report data back.

I am wondering if it would be possible to extend that code, so it would also raise an event on received data from the printer. I don't know though if that's possible at all based on extension of that code.

```
    //something like
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ReadPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ReadPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwRead);
```

Comment: You need to add the code you have tried.

Comment: of course share your coding parts for better understand what you having ????

Comment: Its a Zebra printer

something like
 [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ReadPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwRead);

Comment: code is in that article i made sugestion in main question, but how would that become an event? and the sugestion is mainly in idea form i wonder how it is done.

Comment: You are controlling the printer so you *know* when you write a command that causes the printer to send something back.  Then you call ReadPrinter.  Make the 2nd argument byte[] btw.

Comment: @Hans the code i wrote was really guessed i wonder what would be needed

Comment: I need to get data from Zebra too. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to read data from a printer, for my POS printers ReadPrinter() returns always false.

Comment: sorry i am off this project without access to that code anymore.

Comment: sorry i am off this project and i have no access to that code anymore.
the best starting point is that microsoft article., or as work around which i've did also use raw txt printer, and use that to send commands in zebra language... if your going that way, you also might make your own printer driver basicly ids just general raw IO communication, based upon zebra language, its what our team did in the end.
Be aware tough that those printers have firmware bugs, not every command works we had problms with printqueue etc.